# Как сделать кнопки разной высоты в тулбаре bootstrap4

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap4

При переходе с bootstrap 3 на bootstrap 4 возникла, некоторая проблема, а именно, в 3ей версии, несколько кнопок разного размера обёрнуты в тулбар. В 4й версии, все кнопки в тулбаре автоматически имеют высоту самого большого элемента, например:

Эта разметка в 3ей версии работает, как надо:

[image: Эта разметка в 3ей версии работает, как надо:]

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">lg</button>
       <button type="button"class="btn btn-default">lg</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">btn</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">btn</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
       <button type="button"class="btn btn-default">sm</button>
       <button type="button"class="btn btn-default">sm</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">xs</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">xs</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как это выглядит в 4й:

[image: Как это выглядит в 4й:]

В четвертой версии эта же разметка не работает должным образом (даже не обращая внимания, что в 4‑й версии нету класса '.btn-group-xs')

Хотя в [документации](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/button-group/#button-toolbar) ни слова не сказано об отличиях от 3ей версии в поведении элементов.

---

**Вопрос:** как можно сделать группы кнопок разного размера, обернув их в тулбар?

Если никак нельзя, тогда возникает следующий вопрос:

Без тулбара кнопки выглядят вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их можно выровнять по верху?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется это хак, но я думаю тулбар подразумевает один размер по высоте, подключена 5 версия она не ругается в консоли но в 4 ой работает я проверил.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="btn-toolbar d-flex">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg align-self-start">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">lg</button>
         <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary">lg</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group align-self-start">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">btn</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">btn</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm align-self-start">
        <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary">sm</button>
        <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary">sm</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs align-self-start">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">xs</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">xs</button>
    </div>
</div>
```